# Is there an IDE for PHP CLI?

Tags: ide, php

I downloaded Eclipse PDT, Zend, and Netbeans (trial) and they only seem to have support for PHP on a web server. I want to use PHP CLI as a programming language, is there an IDE for it?

Edit: I don't want to use the command line. I want a program that can run PHP CLI in a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Komodo** allows you to run your scripts in CGI environment.

**NuSphere** has command line tab.

**Zend Studio** has PHP CLIs both version 4 and version 5 installed within the IDE,

**PHP CLI** PHP IDE allows you to quickly test PHP CLI script,

Answer (score 0):

You can write PHP code with any editor, including the ones you mentioned and run it from the command line like this:

```
php yourscript.php
```

The file syntax should be as usual, your script should start with  so they can be processed by the interpreter

Answer (score 0):

NuSphere PHPEd supports PHP CLI.